# How to load xml file from sub directory of WCF?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

In my WCF class library I need to load XML file with some data from sub directory.

```
Example

/doc/file.xml
```

I cannot map path, because HttpContext.Current always null.

What will be the right way to load xml file?

Comment: Why don't you use the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on ASP.NET Compability mode to enable access to the ASP.NET pipeline (HttpContext.Current etc.) from WCF.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

--larsw